# Display ListView when button Click

Tags: android, mysql, button, android-intent, android-listview

I'm new to android and I hope someone could help me here. I have an activity Faculty and a button.

This is my XML layout browse_faculty:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="searchFSTEHandler"
    android:id="@+id/bFSTE"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bFBE"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bFBE"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/fste" />
```

and this is my Faculty Activity which displays the buttons:
I use Intent to view ListView

```
public class Faculty extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle BrowseFaculty) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(BrowseFaculty);
        setContentView(R.layout.browse_faculty);
    }

    //on the XML,this is the "searchFSTEHandler" i want to use to show ListView
    public void searchFSTEHandler(View target){
        Intent courseList = new Intent(this, HttpActivity.class);
        startActivity(courseList);
    }
}
```

and below is the "HttpActivity" class is the class that displays my ListView. This class read a php file which gets data from a MySQL server and converts to JSON data then parses it into a array list.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class HttpActivity extends ListActivity {

public String f1 = "FSTE";




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.faculty_course);


    new getHttp().execute();

    getHttp test =new getHttp();


    String strJsonData = test.doInBackground(f1);

    // Convert String JSON data to Java class
    ArrayList<Courses> arrayCourse= test.parseJsonData(strJsonData);

    //Create an ArrayAdapter which shows the ArrayList data
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Courses>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayCourse));



}




private class getHttp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  public getHttp() { 











  }

  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... faculty) {



    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/sqlWebService.php?faculty=FSTE");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        is = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";

    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

//------------------------------------------------------  
  private ArrayList<Courses> parseJsonData(String strJson) {
        ArrayList<Courses> Course = new ArrayList<Courses>();

        try {
            // Generate JSONArray object by JSON String data
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strJson);

            //from the JSONArray, get one element (row) of JSONData
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                //Get JSON Object which is one element of the array
                JSONObject ob = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Courses exam = new Courses();
                //get the value by key, and set to exam class
                exam.setCode(ob.optString("code"));

                //save exam class to exam array list
                Course.add(exam);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Course;
    }





 }









 }
```

The application crashes as soon as I click on the button and gives a error:
"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Help Please !

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is network operation like what you are trying to do cannot and should not be performed on the main UI thread. Doing so will lead to an **ANR (Android Not Responding)**, which is exactly the kind of error you are getting just now. What you want to do is move your code to a separate thread or to an **`AsyncTask`** that will perform this action in the background on a different thread using the **`doInBackground()`** method which does not have access to your views on the main UI thread. For example,

```
private class ExampleOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public ExampleOperation() { //ctor }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //things that you want to initialize and maybe show dialog to user.
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       //this is where you perform that network related operation.  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //this is where get the results from the network related task.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
       //you can update your progressbar if any; otherwise omit method.
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do is call the AsyncTask where ever you want to use it: `new ExampleOperation().execute();`

Comment: It is pretty much the same as any other class constructor; it would be: `public ExampleOperation() {}`

Comment: Remember to accept the best answer that helps you to accomplish your task; this is a way to give credit to the author and to the community.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to include the constructor, also the usage syntax.

Comment: Hi Karey, I have updated my HttpActivity.class and run it, it still gives the same error...please help

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply; I'm a bit in and out today, but have a look at this tutorial and let me know if you have a better understanding of the AsyncTask process: [Connect Android to PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make HTTP calls in the main thread, they take too long and would make the UI unresponsive.  You need to do it in an AsyncTask.

Comment: please elaborate more or other aproches i can take please...im soo new to this :/

Comment: An AsyncTask is a class you can inherit from that will run a function on another thread without having a permanent thread sitting around.  Http calls can't occur on the main thread, so they are frequently done in an AsyncTask instead.  Example:  http://pcfandroid.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/http-post-with-asynctask-android-tutorial/